# How to spyOn a function?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', ['$window','MyConfig', function($window,MyConfig){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {

            var w = angular.element($window);
            function adjustTop(){
                var oldtop = scope.top;
                if(oldtop<15){
                    scope.top += 2;
                }else{
                    scope.top = 0;
                }
            }

            if(MyConfig.adjusttop){
                w.bind('scroll', function () {
                    adjustTop();
                });
            };

        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I `spyOn` to detect `adjustTop()` function have been called when `MyConfig.adjusttop` is `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. Testing private members arguably isn't a good idea because it couples your tests to a specific implementation, making them fragile.

In general you should test what your code *does*, not *how* it does it. In this case, you could write tests to ensure the `scope.top` property is correctly updated after the `scroll` event has been triggered.

**Updated to address OP's comment:**

Here's a way for you to test what you want:

```
describe('my test', function() {
  var $scope, $window, $compile, MyConfigMock;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    MyConfigMock = {};

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('MyConfig', MyConfigMock);
    });

    inject(function($rootScope, _$window_, _$compile_) {
      $scope = $rootScope;
      $window = _$window_;
      $compile = _$compile_;
    });
  });

  it('updates top on scroll if set to do so', function() {
    // Arrange
    MyConfigMock.adjusttop = true;
    $scope.top = 15;
    $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);

    // Act
    $($window).trigger('scroll');

    // Assert
    expect($scope.top).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5k0iLsumO5YxgjViiAWB?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Michael for your advice. But my directive should look something like this as I have updated my question. So, how can I ensure that `adjustTop` is only functioning when `Myconfig.adjusttop` is set to `true`?

Comment: @user1995781 I've just updated my answer to address your comment.